# How set records priority in order to display HTML?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I am setting up a website in flask, and I want to set a post order from newest to oldest blog post. Posts are inside the database, where I created an id, where the oldest post has id = 0 and the newest post = 1, and so on. It turns out that in jinja html, the post starts from 0 to 1, and want the opposite.

I was searching just to set an ID for each line, but I need help in establishing this order, thank you for your attention.

this is the code of my html page with jinja

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}

        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">

            <div class="article-metadata">

              <a class="mr-2" href="/{{post.url}}">{{ post.title }}    {{post.id}}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.author }}</small>
            </div>
           <div id="description_2" class="article-content"><a>{{ post.short_description }}</a></div>
          </div>
    {%endif%}
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display posts sorted by id in descending order you need to order the query before passing it to the context.

`posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.id.desc()).all()`